# Blender Cloth, Single object with two meshes, wanting to keep them joined for first few frames of cloth physics

Tags: mesh, physics, cloth-simulation

Hello fellow Blenderer's

I am working on a small project where I have a character eating and when the food moves away from mouth **I want to form a string of dribble that stretches then separates in half and fall.**

as seen in my simple animation here. I am wanting the two middle points to stay joined for longer. Glued if you will!

[image]

the Object is a tube which is separated in the middle. I use KeyShapes to make the tube go from thick to skinny in the middle during the animation.

[image]
[image]
Not sure on how to accomplish gluing them together for longer.

Answer (score 1):

Hook modifier could do it, but there is perhaps a way to do it through simulation which would give better results.

Comment: The animation above is not keyshaped so to speak!, the cloth simulation is moving it.. but the keyshapes are making it go really thin in the middle (where the two split)  I will take a look at hooks :)

Comment: Tried Hooks, tried separating the mesh into two objects and hooking them to each other. but hook does not hold them